# Import Complex Sphinx Translations into Weblate

Tags: weblate

I'm using `import_project` to bring in components from a sphinx document set.  Where this is falling apart is my sub directory structure:

```
 - docs
  - _locale
   - fr
    - LC_MESSAGES
     - file.po
     - file2.po
      - directory
       - file.po
       - file2.po        
      - directory2
       - file.po
       - file2.po
```

The import command `./manage.py import_project --file-format po project-name git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git master 'docs/_locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/**.po'` doesn't look at the `directory` and it's sub files.  Further because the sub directory files has like named files, there is a conflict how the `import_project` would map files to components (if I run `import_project` for each sub directory).

Any tips?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way right now, but you can import them folder by folder.

```
$ ./manage.py import_project --name-template 'Directory 1: %s' \
    --file-format po \
    project https://github.com/project/docs.git master \
    'docs/locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/dir1/**.po'
$ ./manage.py import_project --name-template 'Directory 2: %s' \
    --file-format po \
    project https://github.com/project/docs.git master \
    'docs/locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/dir2/**.po'
```

PS: I've also added this example to the [documentation](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/devel/sphinx.html).

Update: There are more comfortable ways to configure Sphinx documentation localization these days.

- Configure Sphinx to generate just a single PO file using [gettext_compact](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-gettext_compact) setting.
- Use discovery addon in Weblate as described in the [Weblate documentation](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/devel/sphinx.html).

Comment: Fantastic!  I missed the relevance of the `--name-template` parameter to this problem.